# Enable keyboard support on Arch Linux for Chromebook

Tags: linux, keyboard, arch-linux, chromebook

I got sick of ChromeOS, and decided to install Linux.

My first choice was GalliumOS, since it is pretty much made to support ChromeBooks, however I got annoyed when it didn't allow me to uninstall xfce4, without uninstalling GalliumOS itself.

I decided to try Arch, since there is a wide range of customization, and I can install everything by hand.

However, there is a problem... The keyboard doesn't work!

The only button that works is the power button.

I have a HP Chromebook 11 G5, with 16GB EMMC card and 4GB ram.

Is there some sort of kernel patch or package that I can install to the Arch Linux installation media (my USB)?

Comment: It could be a driver issue.  Arch may not have gravitated to Chromebooks yet.

Comment: Arch has a [whole wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Chrome_OS_devices#Hotkeys) on running on Chromebook hardware.  There's a section on configuring the top row of keys but nothing otherwise.  This is pretty strange: I wonder if your installation media is corrupt.  FYI: I installed Fedora on a Dell 13 with no issues.